# Echo alternative $_GET request method

Tags: php, get

I'm aware of this method:

```
stackoverflow.com/?id=stack

<?php 
   echo $_GET['id'];
   //output: stack
?>
```

But I would like to know how to get $_GET request if url is like this:

```
stackoverflow.com/?stack

<?php 
   echo ???
   //output: stack
?>
```

Notice that content after `/?` is dynamically changed.

Comment: You should probably check out mod_rewrite, URL rewriting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the whole query string (unparsed) with `$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']`

Answer (score 2):

You can retrieve all values of $_GET like this:

```
<?php
foreach($_GET as $key => $value){
 // $key = 'stack';
 // $value = '';
}
```

However, you *should* know what values are possible in your application and code appropriately for them.

Comment: @phihag, output from `print_r($_GET)` on `.?stack` = `Array ( [stack] => )`

Comment: Yup, sorry, screwed up the test.

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php
$key = 'stack';
echo array_key_exists( $key, $_GET ) ? $key : NULL;
?>
```

I just noticed your comment:

> Notice that content after /? is dynamically changed.

If you just want to do something dynamically with whatever appears in the query string, then the other answers regarding looping over `$_GET` or accessing `$_SERVER[ 'QUERY_STRING' ]` might suit you better (really depends what you're doing).  Another possibility for a situation like that is `array_keys( $_GET )`

Comment: `$_GET` is empty for the request `?stack`. Also, why would you default  to `NULL` instead of `''`?

Comment: `$_GET` will not be empty for that request -- it will be populated with an element with key `stack` and value of empty string.  "Also, why would you default to NULL instead of ''" -- it doesn't particularly matter in this case. NULL would be converted to string, in this case the empty string.

Comment: Oops, you're totally right. I must have screwed up the test somehow. nevertheless, this variant does not work for `key = 'x&y';`

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean.  For `/?x&y`, `$_GET` will be populated with 2 elements, with keys `x` and `y` and empty string values. If you want a key of `x&y` you'd have to percent encode the ampersand in the URL (assuming ampersand is the param separator, which is not a given).

Comment: There are scenarios where you don't want to let php parse your query string. For example, you may want to allow multiple (identical) keys, or collect the whole query string to include it in an administration panel.

Comment: Yes, but the question seems to indicate that the OP expects PHP to parse the query string. I also don't understand the connection between what you mention here and in your previous comment.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [$_SERVER](http://php.net/manual/es/reserved.variables.server.php) to get a lot of information about the URL, like

```
$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
```

Answer (score 2):

[`$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']`](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php) contains the value you're looking for. Try:

```
<?php
echo $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
```

Answer (score 2):

It would be $_GET['stack'] with null value.

There is a superglobal $_GET array. I believe checking it out on php.net would help.

http://localhost/?stack

Code:

```
<?php
echo var_dump($_GET);
```

Output:

```
array(1) {
  ["stack"]=>
  string(0) ""
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can just go through contents of `$_GET` and see what's inside. In your case `stack` will be key with empty string as value.

Additionally you can use [`parse_url`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) and check `query` key from results, which is the same as using `$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']` as described in other answers.

But maybe it would help more if you described what are you trying to achieve.

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php
$d = array_keys($_GET);
echo array_shift($d);
?>
```